# Powershell - Adding users to groups in another domain

Tags: powershell, cross-domain, powershell-3.0, active-directory-group

Anyone know how to add a user to a group in another domain that is trusted?

Say I'm logged into a computer in domain apple and I want to add a user (in domain orange) to group `sg-California` in domain orange. How do I login with my other domain admin credentials to run the command:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity sg-California -Members userindomainorange
```

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I found that you needed to point powershell at a domain controller and have your credentials input into a var.

```
# User to add
$User = Read-Host "Enter user samid"

# Domain controller to run against
$TargetDomainController = "dc01.domain.loc"

# Get credentials
$AdminCredsTargetDomain = Get-Credential TargetDomain\user

# Run command
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup -Members $User -Server $TargetDomainController -Credential $AdminCredsTargetDomain
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `-Credential` parameter to run the command with your admin credentials. As long as your AD trusts and everything is set up correctly, you shouldn't have a problem.

```
#Get your credentials
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential "DomainOrange\AdminUser"

#Run AD command with credentials
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity sg-California -Members DomainOrange\userindomainorange -Credential $AdminCredentials
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer HAL9256, this got me moving in the right direction.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `"Add-ADGroupMember : A referral was returned from the server"`
when using this method.

I had to resort to using `Set-ADObject: Set-ADObject -Identity GroupDN -Add @{member=MemberDN} -Server DC`

where:

1. `GroupDN` is the distinguished Name of the group
2. `MemberDN` is the distinguished Name of the Member to add
3. `DC` is the domain controller where the group is